# Duplicity: UnsupportedBackendScheme: scheme not supported in url: s3+http://foo.woof.com/?

Tags: duplicity

I installed Duplicity with the helpful damontimm [script](http://blog.damontimm.com/bash-script-incremental-encrypted-backups-duplicity-amazon-s3/) and [advice](http://blog.damontimm.com/how-to-automated-secure-encrypted-incremental-backups-amazon-s3-duplicity-os-x-or-ubuntu/).

I also created an s3 bucket foo.woof.com.

But when I run Duplicity (via the script), I get:

`UnsupportedBackendScheme: scheme not supported in url: s3+http://foo.woof.com/`

What should I do? Do I need to make S3 bucket foo.woof.com available via DNS? (I do know how to do that.)

I am using the `--s3-use-new-style` option.

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is old as but if you still receive this error, run the command with "-v 9" for verbose output. For me it complained that the 'psutil' package was missing on the server, so I installed it with 'pip3 install psutil' and all was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The bug has been fixed by Duplicity developers. 
A [patch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/655468/+attachment/1675322/+files/botobackend.py.diff) against for the problem is now available.

Details: See the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/655468)

Comment: Can you anyone assist me on duply same protocol error: http://askubuntu.com/questions/804792/duply-unsupportedbackendscheme-scheme-not-supported-in-url-sftp-userdomai